# CSS drop-down menu, link cut in half

Tags: css

I'm learning how to build pure CSS drop-down menus, and I'm seeing a weird issue. I've searched and haven't found anything useful.

If you hover over the Blog link, you'll see "Case Studies" split in half with, "Case" on one line and "Studies" on the next line.

I' ve checked my HTML and it looks fine. It's been a long day so maybe I'm missing something obvious. :o

I have this so far:

```
    <nav class="p-nav">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Showcase</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Blog</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Case Studies</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Tutorials</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Javascript</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Playground</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300, 400);

.p-nav li {
    position: relative;
}

.p-nav ul ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
}

.p-nav ul li {
    float: left;
}

.p-nav a {
    display: block;
    font: 300 100%/70px"Lato", sans-serif;
    padding: 0 30px;
}

.p-nav ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}
```

Here is the link to the code: http://jsfiddle.net/6CwYh/20/

Can anyone explain why it's doing that, and how I can fix it?

TIA.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cause of space "problems" it places those two words on two lines.
If you don't like that you can add `white-space:nowrap;`to the `<li>`so it want wrap, have a look at the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6CwYh/21/

```
.p-nav li {
    position: relative;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is simply not enough space for the text to fit, which is why it is wrapping. Give the 2nd level `ul` a width, like 350px.

http://jsfiddle.net/6CwYh/24/

Also, make sure you use direct descendant operators (>) I've added some in the above link.

If I target `#something ul li` That actually will target all uls and all lis in `#something` even if they're nested.

This was causing the items in the dropdowns to float, which caused further problems.

```
/* Better selectors */
#something > ul {}
#something > ul > li {}
#something > ul > li > ul {}
#something > ul > li > ul > li {}
```

Answer (score 0):

make it wider:

```
nav ul li{
    width:200px;
}
```

and its fixed